# How to find demographics (and other audience information) for a single page in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

So Google Analytics has the Audience section, and then under Demographics they tell you age, gender, etc.

But that is for the entire site. Can you show that kind of information for a *specific* page? Eg I'd like to see the age, gender of people who visit my home page. Or the country distribution of people who visit my blog page.

Comment: Hi, this is more appropriate for the Webmasters forum as it is not related to coding. But to comment, you can add a secondary dimension of "page" to see the pages per, for example, age range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to filter any view inside Google analytics by adding secondary dimensions as explained here: [Analytics documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6175970?hl=en). By adding the secondary dimension page or page title you can see how many of age x or gender x viewed that page.